# Why new File(File parent, String childName) behave unobvious?

Tags: java, file

I was stacked for a while with following behavior, if i create file like this:

```
new File("");
```

Then it will point on project working directory, in my case `C:/project/` . If creating file like this:

```
new File("image");
```

Then it will be relative to project directory, in my case `C:/project/image/`. Everything is ok, but if i create file using `new File(File parent, String childName)` constructor, like this:

```
new File(new File(""), "image");
```

Then it will point to `C:/image/`, i starting from the root directory. I found that it is documented behavior:

> If `parent` is the empty abstract pathname then the new
>   `File` instance is created by converting `child`
>   into an abstract pathname and resolving the result against a
>   system-dependent default directory.

But why? Is there any reason? Or "Just because"? Why if i giving `new File("")` which is point's to the **current** directory, as a parent, i will receive child with the **root** directory as parent?

Comment: Use `new File(".")` to point to the working directory...

Comment: This is surely more down to the behaviour of `new File("")`: "If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname."

Comment: @fabian I resolved that problem for myself using `new File(null, "image")` constructor, but question is not about it.

Comment: `new File(File, String)`: "If parent is the empty abstract pathname then the new File instance is created by convertingchild into an abstract pathname and resolving the result against a system-dependent default directory."

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, i think you maybe right here, `new File(String)` have following words in documentation: "If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname." And says nothing about current or any other directory. And OS interprets empty like working directory. And in this way `new File("")` pointing on the working directory can be considered as undocumented behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/File.java#File.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%2Cjava.lang.String%29) shows why there is a difference:

```
/**
 * The FileSystem object representing the platform's local file system.
 */
private static final FileSystem fs = DefaultFileSystem.getFileSystem();

// Snip.

public File(File parent, String child) {
    if (child == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if (parent != null) {
        if (parent.path.equals("")) {
            this.path = fs.resolve(fs.getDefaultParent(),
                                   fs.normalize(child));
        } else {
            this.path = fs.resolve(parent.path,
                                   fs.normalize(child));
        }
    } else {
        this.path = fs.normalize(child);
    }
    this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```

vs

```
public File(String pathname) {
    if (pathname == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
    this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```

i.e. if you pass `new File("")` as the `parent` parameter, the `FileSystem`'s default parent is considered in resolving the path.

All of the methods `FileSystem.getDefaultParent`, `FileSystem.resolve` and 
`FileSystem.normalize` are abstract, so the concrete behaviour is not immediately apparent; however, it is not unreasonable to assume that the different code paths will result in different behaviour.